# Android getImageMatrix() returns wrong Matrix

Tags: android, opencv, matrix, imageview, point

I have an CameraActivity which implements onPictureTaken. In this method I save the image to the public DCIM folder and send an Intent to another PicturePrevActivity.
Here the sender code:

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
           
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
            Matrix rotateMatrix = new Matrix();
            rotateMatrix.postRotate(90);
            Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0,  bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), rotateMatrix, false);

            String savefilename = saveBitmapPublic(rotatedBitmap,Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM,"test.jpg");
            if(savefilename != null) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(CameraActivity.this,PicturePrevActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("picture", savefilename);
                startActivity(intent);
          }  }
```

Here is the code for the recieving PicturePrevActivty in OnCreate() :

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("picture")) {

        try {             
         
            mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent().getStringExtra("picture"));
            mSelectionImageView.setImageBitmap(mMyOpenCVWrapper.getResizedBitmap(mBitmap, MAX_HEIGHT));
            List<PointF> points = mMyOpenCVWrapper.findPoints(mBitmap);
            mSelectionImageView.setPoints(points);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();               
        }

    }
```

For explanation, the findPoints method detects edges per OpenCV on mBitmap and converts these points from the mBitmap to viewpoints of the mSelectionImageView by using this function:

```
 private PointF mapPointToMatrix(PointF point) {
    
    float[] points = new float[] { point.x, point.y };
    mSelectionImageView.getImageMatrix().mapPoints(points);   //this line is the problem, the matrix differs. 
    if (points.length > 1) {
      
        return new PointF(points[0], points[1]);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The resulting Rect is correct, if I start this operations after a buttonclick in the recieving PicturePrevActivty.
But when I start these operations in the OnCreate, OnStart or OnResume procedure of the recieving PicturePrevActivity the resulting Rect is much too small.

Here it gets interessting, if I copy this code to the onCreateOptionsMenu() method it works like a charme:

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main_menu, menu);

    if(getIntent().hasExtra("picture")) {

        try {
                
             mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getIntent().getStringExtra("picture"));
           
            mSelectionImageView.setImageBitmap(mMyOpenCVWrapper.getResizedBitmap(mBitmap, MAX_HEIGHT));
            List<PointF> points = mMyOpenCVWrapper.findPoints(mBitmap);
            mSelectionImageView.setPoints(points);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(PicturePrevActivity.this,"Error reading picture",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

    return true;
}
```

As I marked in the code, the getImageMatrix() method is the problem in this construct. It should deliver
Matrix{[1.856, 0.0, 12.0][0.0, 1.856, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}, but it delivers
Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}
if I call it in OnCreate, OnStart or OnResume. It only works, when used in onCreateOptionsMenu().

Can someone help me here, please? Why returns getImageMatrix() only the right points, when called in onCreateOptionsMenu()? Whats my fault?

Edit 2021-07-16: Does nobody have an advice for me?

Many thanks in advance!
Best regards,
mc

Answer (score 0):

here is what the official doc says:

> Returns the view's optional matrix. This is applied to the view's drawable when it is drawn. If there is no matrix, this method will return an identity matrix. Do not change this matrix in place but make a copy. If you want a different matrix applied to the drawable, be sure to call setImageMatrix().

You are getting an Identity matrix in `onCreate` / `onResume` / `onStart` because the matrix is not "ready" yet. I guess you will have to find a way to know when the matrix is "ready" before trying to get it.

I suggest to use **Glide** or **Picasso** library to load your bitmap image like so:

```
Picasso.get().load(new File(getIntent().getStringExtra("picture")))
             .into(mSelectionImageView, new Callback() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(){
                       // image is ready
                   }

                   @Override
                   public void onError(Exception ex){
                       // image loading failed
                   }
             });
```

Note: The Callback param is a strong reference and will prevent your Activity or Fragment from being garbage collected. If you use this method, it is strongly recommended you invoke an adjacent Picasso.cancelRequest(android.widget.ImageView) call to prevent temporary leaking.